# jQuery UI Dialog: Maintain within window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have several dialogs that I want to function the same way.  I create an empty dialog, load the dialog with various content via ajax depending on which buttons are clicked, and then open the dialog.  Upon opening I check the window height and if the dialog height is greater than the window height I set the height to the window size minus 20px, otherwise the dialog height is auto.  I run this same function on the window resize event and also position it in the center of the window.  I also run the function when certain button are clicked inside the dialog that append data to the end of the dialog.  Everything works great except it breaks the manual resizing of the dialog using the drag handles. I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2.  The code basically is like so:

```
    //Create the dialog
    $("div.myDialogContainer").dialog({
      title:"Whatever",
      autoOpen:false,
      modal:true,
      resizable:true,
      width:850,
      open:function(event, ui){$.positionDialog();}
    });

    //Load content and open the dialog
    $("#openButton").on("click", function(){
      $.ajax({url:"myPath", success:function(data){
        $("div.myDialogContainer").html(data).dialog("open");
        $("div.myDialogContainer #addMoreData").on("click", function(){
          $("div.myDialogontainer div.loadedContent").append("<div>More Data</div>");
        });
      }
      });
    });

    //Position the dialog on window resize
    $(window).resize(function(){$.positionDialog();});

    //check dialog height and center on screen
    (function(){$.positionDialog=function(){
      var myDialog = $("div.myDialogContainer:visible"); 
      var availableHeight = $(window).height() - 20;
      var dialogHeight = myDialog.parent().height();
      if(dialogHeight>=availableHeight){
        myDialog.dialog("option", "height", availableHeight );
      }
      else{
        myDialog.dialog("option", "height", "auto" );} 
        myDialog.dialog("option", "position", "center");
      }
    })(jQuery);
```

Am I missing something here or is this just a bug/limitation of jQuery/jQuery UI??

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replcates problem

Comment: Here is a link to the jsFiddle I created. As you can see, I run the function to position the dialog and check the height upon opening the dialog.  Resizing the dialog with the handles is broken. http://jsfiddle.net/Big_A_Rob/q3V6m/